# 12 Column Responsive Design - Article and Aside Not Formatting Properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a template for a responsive website.

My first problem is that the Article and Aside are supposed to be side by side. I'm using a 12-column system with rows, and I assigned both the Article and Aside to a div class of "col-6" meaning that they should each take up 50% of the width of the container. I don't understand why they're doing this:

[image]

The Article and Aside should almost touch each other in the center. As you will see in the code, they are each within a div class "row", so they should be in the same row. My second problem is that since this is a responsive website, I need the Article and Aside to fit on top of each other as the page reaches mobile size (600px and below). But that isn't happening correctly.

[image]

I do not fully understand the 12 column / media query system, so this could be part of the problem. I'm using this tutorial from W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. What I'm most confused about is that when we add the media query at the bottom of the CSS file, its styles - the 12 columns - are applied *after* the page reaches 600px. So shouldn't this mean that all of the CSS before the media query will not apply to the page once it reaches 600px? After testing, I can see that the styles still apply, but then shouldn't this mean that I need to create another media query with (min-width:0px) and 12 columns for when the page is smaller than 600px? Otherwise the 12 columns only apply once the page hits 600px, right? Thanks for the help!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SASS Project</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"><!--container-->

<div class="row"><!--first row--> 
<header>  
    <div class="center">                        
       <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
</header>
</div><!--end first row-->

<nav><!--Nav Bar-->
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="row"><!--second row-->
<div class="col-6">
<article><!--Article-->
<h2>Article</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus 
vel tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. 
Cras feugiat scelerisque risus 
eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar. Morbi posuere ligula 
in aliquam feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus vestibulum molestie.
Donec mollis at odio 
id tempor.</p>
<img src="images/image1.jpg" id="image1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar. 
Morbi posuere ligula in aliquam 
feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis
 at odio id tempor.</p>
</article>
</div>


<div class="col-6">
<aside><!--Aside-->
<h2>Aside</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus 
eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar. Morbi posuere ligula in
 aliquam 
feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis
 at odio 
id tempor.</p>
<img src="images/image2.jpg" id="image2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar.
 Morbi posuere ligula in aliquam feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus
 vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis at odio id tempor.</p>
</aside>
</div>
</div><!--end second row-->

<section><!--Section-->
<h2>Section</h2>
</section>

<div class="clearfix">
</div>

<!-- 3 column layout -->
<div class="content">
<h2>3 Column Layout</h2>

<div class="leftcol"> <h4>Content 1</h4>
</div><!--closes leftcol-->

<div class="rightcol"> <h4>Content 3</h4>
</div><!--closes rightcol-->

<div class="midcol"> <h4>Content 2</h4>
</div><!--closes midcol-->

</div>

<footer><!--Footer-->
<h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>

</div><!--closes container-->
</body><!--closes body-->

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{overflow:scroll}/*for tablets and phones*/

*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.row:after{content:"";
       clear:both;
       display:block;}

[class*="col-"]{float:left;
            padding:10px;}


/*global styles*/
#container {height:auto;
            margin:auto;
            max-width:1000px;
            width:100%}

header {width:100%;
       height:40px;
       background-color:red;
       margin-bottom:15px;}

nav ul{list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration:none;
      text-align:center;
      margin-bottom:15px;}

nav ul li a{display:inline;
            margin-left:15px;
            text-decoration:none;}

nav ul li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

h2 {text-align:center;}

h4 {display: block;}

#image1 {float:left;
        height:160px;
        width:160px;}

#image2 {float:right;
        height:160px;
        width:160px;}

article{width:45%;
        margin-right:5%;
        float:left;
        height:600px;
        background-color:green;}

aside{width:45%;
      float:right;
      height:600px;
      background-color:green;}

.clearfix{clear:both;}


footer {width:100%;
       height:25px;
       background-color:red;
       margin-bottom:15px;
       clear:both;}

.content{width:auto;
         height:auto;
         clear:both;
         background-color:red;}   

.leftcol{width:30%;
         float:left;}

.midcol{width:30%;
        margin-left:35%;}

.rightcol{width:30%;
          float:right;}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

nav ul li {display:inline;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your column size is set to col-6 which is 50% of a small screen. (and all other screens if you don't specify the other sizes) BUT your **article** and **aside** element is set to: width: 45% ..

So if you want them to fit into the col-6 grids, you will have to change this to 100% i've done it here in a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1u9o4b4/1/

```
    article{width:100%;
        margin-right:5%;
        float:left;
        height:600px;
        background-color:green;}

aside{width:100%;
      float:right;
      height:600px;
      background-color:green;}
```

Now if you wanted the Aside and Article to stay that skinny but still be side by side, you should not use the col-sm-6 tag. I have made another fiddle for this solution using col-4:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1u9o4b4/2/

```
article{width:100%;
        margin-right:5%;
        float:left;
        height:600px;
        background-color:green;}

aside{width:100%;
      float:right;
      height:600px;
      background-color:green;}
```

and

```
<div class="col-4">
```

**edit** Here's a version with the overflow of the aside and article set to scroll: https://jsfiddle.net/x1u9o4b4/3/

Comment: Thank you. Yeah that was it. I don't need them to stay skinny with a scroll, but still good to know. So what is it in my code that makes the article and aside fit on top of each other as the page goes from desktop to mobile (600px and smaller)?

Comment: That is default bootstrap behaviour for rows, it is trying to keep your mobile-friendly since the screen got so small. In order to fix this, you can specify screen sizes with your columns. It looks like you only have a basic version of the 12 column structure in your css, so you don't even have the screen sizes. I've added them for you here:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1u9o4b4/6/

      <div class="col-xs-6">

Comment: Oh I don't need to fix it, I just wondered why it was doing that since I didn't specify this anywhere in my code. But where is .col-xs-6 is the CSS?

Comment: I just attached the bootstrap css, and that covered all the columns. Its on the left side under external resources.

Comment: I clicked external resources and this is my screen: http://i.imgur.com/lPCYA6K.jpg

Tried clicking little blue cross next to JavaScript/CSS URI but still nothing

Comment: all I did was attach this CSS: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css